# In java Restfull web application, if request parameters are changing(some times full request, some time some absent ,and data type is also different)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

In java Restfull web application, if request parameters are changing(some times full request, some time some absent) and data type is also different.

how we can handle?

Comment: then probably you have to refactor your API, I really don't see why you should change the type of the same parameter

Comment: You will have to have multiple APIs to handle this scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to setup a service that has several endpoints/methods for different purposes, this way you would be able to handle this accurately. Having the same endpoint having to deal with multiple requests/responses is not only (close to) impossible, it would also be a code smell and problematic for code maintenance. You would not want to have to use this kind of API yourself.

There's tools available, e.g. Spotlight, that can help you design an API.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's a common scenario to mark request parameters optional. In that case, in the parameter list request handler method (*methods annotated with @GetMapping, @PostMapping, etc*), you could annotate that particular parameter with **@RequestParam(required = false)**

For example, If you request parameter named dummy which is int by type and optional you can use

```
@RequestParam(name = "dummy", required = false) Integer dummyValue
```

In this case, the dummyValue will be null when the parameter is optional (*as **Integer** is a reference type, not primitive type*)

---

However, if you use

```
@RequestParam(name = "dummy", required = false) int dummyValue
```

the default value of variable will be changed to default value of that particular primitive type when that parameter is optional(false for boolean, 0 for int, etc.)
(Though I will personally prefer using Integer instead of int)

---

So, you can put conditions to check value of request paramater and determine accordingly.

---

As for request parameter with changing data type, It's not possible in Java to assign multiple types to a single variable(though you can always go for Object data type as it's supertype of all reference type in java). But, you'll lose the strongly-typed paradigm java provides.

---

I will personally suggest you create another request parameter instead.